# How do I register and log-in a User in django-rest-framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have no idea how to do it. I just want to know the best way to register and/or log-in a User through rest API. I would be thankful for any code snippets or documentatnion links.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at `djoser`

https://djoser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html